# proguard.ParseException: Expecting class member name before '@' in Android Eclipse ADT

Tags: android, proguard

i try to optimize my Android Application code using Proguard with eclipse ADT v21.1.0-569685 on MAC.
i used project->Android Tools->export asigned Application package option for signing with my private certificate,on finish of signing i got following error,

**project.properties**

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.
#
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

# Project target.
target=android-17
android.library.reference.1=../google-play-services_lib
```

**proguard-project.txt**

```
# To enable ProGuard in your project, edit project.properties
# to define the proguard.config property as described in that file.
#
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in ${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the ProGuard
# include property in project.properties.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}
```

**Console Log:**

```
[2013-04-12 10:41:53 - MyApp] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2013-04-12 10:41:53 - MyApp] proguard.ParseException: Expecting class member name before '@' in line 82 of file '/Users/MyOrg/Android_workspace/MyApp/bin/proguard.txt',
[2013-04-12 10:41:53 - MyApp]   included from argument number 6
[2013-04-12 10:41:53 - MyApp]   at proguard.ConfigurationParser.readNextWord(ConfigurationParser.java:1133)
[2013-04-12 10:41:53 - MyApp]   at proguard.ConfigurationParser.readNextWord(ConfigurationParser.java:1117)
[2013-04-12 10:41:53 - MyApp]   at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseMemberSpecificationArguments(ConfigurationParser.java:845)
[2013-04-12 10:41:53 - MyApp]   at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseClassSpecificationArguments(ConfigurationParser.java:697)
[2013-04-12 10:41:53 - MyApp]   at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseKeepClassSpecificationArguments(ConfigurationParser.java:490)
[2013-04-12 10:41:53 - MyApp]   at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parse(ConfigurationParser.java:139)
[2013-04-12 10:41:53 - MyApp]   at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:484)
```

1. How to solve the above issue?
2. In prouard.project file I read

> If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following and
>   specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
>   class:

I have used webview in two activity with WebAppInterface.java class.How to do above statement?

Comment: Have you looked at line 82 of `/Users/MyOrg/Android_workspace/MyApp/bin/proguard.txt`?

Comment: -keepclassmembers class * { *** @string/tha_lf_et_todate_onclick(...); }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Referring resource name like "**@string/on_click_handler_name**", in **android:onClick** attribute of your layout file is ok. However, proguard cannot resolve these references.

Check http://android.okhelp.cz/proguard-parseexception-expecting-class-member-name-before/ for more details.

Find corresponding value of **@string/tha_lf_et_todate_onclick** in your *string.xml* and update :

```
android:onClick="@string/tha_lf_et_todate_onclick"
```

to

```
android:onClick="onClickXXX"
```

in your layout file.
For the second question,
uncomment that piece of code, and replace "fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview"
with the class's fully qualified name.